# A word that means "blending into a community too much"

Tags: word-request, verbs

I found two phrasal verbs that are close to the meaning I want to convey:

1- **Fit in**: to feel that you belong to a particular group and are accepted by that group.

2- **Blend into**: to look or seem the same as surrounding people or things and therefore not be easily noticeable.

What I want to convey is blending into a community to the extent of losing one's characteristics and personality. It is as being too flexible that you can easily fit in in any community whether it was suitable for your nature or not.

I want to fill the verb in the blank of the following sentence:

> Fitting in is one thing, but ______ communities is a totally different thing.

---

The phrasal verb "blend into" means "يختلط" in Arabic which also means "mix". The verb I'm looking for means "يذوب" which also means "dissolving/melting" but they don't seem (according to my research) to be used in English in that way.

Comment: "*being too flexible that you can easily fit in in any community whether it was suitable for your nature or not.*"  This makes no sense.  If you're that "flexible", and you do "flex" that much, then it **is** in your nature to fit in that much.

Comment: Yes, I think it is a bit redundant for the sake of explaining the meaning I wanted to convey.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Assimilation" can work here:

> [**assimilation**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/assimilation) (n): The absorption and integration of people, ideas, or culture into a wider society or culture.

Assimilation is a neutral term for a process that can be expressed either as a positive or a negative.  To those in the wider culture, it may seem a *good* result to see some minority culture integrated into the majority -- but to those in the minority culture who would like to maintain their heritage, assimilation can be a worrisome.

As an example: For a long time the United States was thought of as a ["melting pot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_pot#United_States) in which people of all nations, cultures, and creeds would mix together (like different metals when heated) to become one homogeneous whole.  In this model, assimilation is viewed as a *positive* result.

More recently this was replaced with the model of ["cultural pluralism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_pluralism) (also known as the "fruit salad" model) in which different cultures retain their uniqueness but still mix harmoniously with all the other unique cultural groups.  In this model, assimilation is, perhaps, inevitable, but still viewed as a somewhat *negative* result.

(Edit) Because the noun assimilation exists, the gerund *assimilating* has a slightly different nuance that refers more to the process than the result.  In your example sentence, I prefer to use "assimilation":

> Fitting in is one thing, but **assimilation** is another.

However, when comparing two things, it's nice if you can phrase them similarly:

> **Accommodation** is one thing, but assimilation is another.

or

> **Integration** is one thing, but assimilation is another.

Comment: Just a note that here we would want the verb form: *Fitting in is one thing, but assimilating communities is a different thing*.  I think of [the Borg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg) from *Star Trek: The Next Generation* as an example of the negative side of assimilation.

Comment: Another metaphor used for cultural pluralism, especially in Canada, is the "cultural mosaic," which is meant to evoke a model where each individual piece of the mosaic retains its distinct individual shape and color, but together they form a picture that's greater than the sum of its parts.

Comment: Thank you all. @NateEldredge _ If I omitted "communities", would it be *... but assimilation is a different thing*?

Comment: I think it's important to note that when using the verb form, the community assimilates the individual, and not the other way around. You could also say that the individual is assimilated into the community.

Comment: @DavidK _ Thank you for explaining the form issue. **Assimilated into** is similar to **Blending into** but more than just blending; it makes a great fit.

Comment: @TasneemZH You could also say "assimilated *by*", but I view that as more negative connotation, possibly implying assimilation by force (like the Borg).

Comment: @TasneemZH  While they are similar, "blend in" and "assimilate" are only loose synonyms.  When you *blend* two things together, the mix still retains the unique character of both.  When one thing is *assimilated* into another, it essentially loses its unique character.  This is why the order is important -- A assimilating into B is *not* the same as B assimilating into A.

Comment: @Andrew _ Understood. Thank you so much for explaining and suggesting two better ways of rephrasing my sentence. I think I will go with the second one as "accommodation" is chiefly British, and I write in American-English.

Comment: @TasneemZH  I'm American, and I wouldn't say that "accommodation" is particularly British ...  although, I suppose any kind of formal or educated writing does kind of *sound* that way.  If you really want to sound "American" you might rephrase completely:  **"It's one thing to do your best to fit in to society, but another thing to assimilate into it."**  Still, the U.S. is a big country, with a wide range of writing styles.  Some of us can't even write in complete sentences.

Comment: @Andrew _ Dictionaries can be misleading sometimes. *Grammarly Dictionary, Cambridge, and Google first-result-search Dictionary* all agree that the word is either *British* or *mainly/chiefly British*. In your suggestion you used *fit in*, it may be the best choice after all if what is needed is pure American-English writing.

Comment: @TasneemZH  "Accommodation" has two definitions.  The one that refers to *"a place to live, work, stay, etc. in:"* is chiefly British, but only when singular.  In the US it's plural (*"accommodations"*).   The other definition is universal.

Answer (score 22):

I don't have a simple verb to replace your blank, but consider *[going native](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/119808/216106):*

> Fitting in is one thing, but *going native* is a totally different thing.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-native):

**go native**
disapproving or humorous

​*If a person who is in a foreign country goes native, they begin to live and/or dress like the people who live there.*

Comment: tbh since it is only used these days to indicate that the sayer of the phrase is old-fashioned and out of touch with current events (see for example hastur and crowley in Good Omens) "gone native" is becoming more of a compliment these days.

Comment: This expression has some baggage, though - it carries a certain negative connotation and would generally be understood as applying to a person from a developed country who has assimilated into a culture which may be perceived as tribal, colonial, or primitive.  It could easily reflect badly on the person using this expression as it sort of implies that the person saying it thinks poorly of said culture and, by extension, of the person who has "gone native".  Using this phrase paints the speaker with a degree of racist attitude.

Comment: **Going native** is a very good suggestion but it is a bit more than what I want to convey. I wanted a word that describes the changing of one's characteristics and personality, not to the point of his/her identity and culture.

Comment: @TasneemZH "Going native" *absolutely* describes adopting parts of the culture you find yourself in, even while maintaining other parts. It doesn't mean fully joining their culture and rejecting your original one.

Comment: @J... Strongly disagree that it necessarily implies the culture is "primitive." It depends on the culture in question. For example, it would certainly not mean that if I as an American said someone "went native" in Britain; I would clearly be saying they had adopted many of the mannerisms that are unusual in America and common in Britain. Besides that, the author is clearly *trying* to express disapproval. Concerns of sounding "racist" are likely secondary here.

Comment: "[going native] doesn't mean fully joining their culture and rejecting your original one." I would somewhat disagree. When I've seen it used, it always means that the person has come to have more loyalty to their adopted culture than to their original culture. The original culture isn't necessarily rejected, but it's not the preferred culture.

Comment: @jpmc26 You can't just unilaterally decide what a phrase means - maybe it doesn't mean that to you, but it is a phrase that is deeply rooted in colonialism.  Saying of an American that they "went native" in Britain just sounds like you don't understand what the phrase means and are misusing it in a clumsy way.  Either that or you are attempting deliberately to 'colonialize' the US/UK relationship in a way that is disparaging to the latter's culture.  You can certainly control what you think this phrase means, but other people will interpret it differently.

Comment: @jpmc26 Also, OP is trying to express disapproval of the person who is trying too hard to pretend they belong in the target culture - they aren't necessarily trying to be disparaging of the target culture itself.  This phrase necessarily does both.

Comment: @J... https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=go%20native "...often said of people who go to foreign countries or far away cities. These traits may include dress, language, accent, etiquette, religion, etc." I think it's rather that you're just not familiar with the lighter colloquial use.

Comment: @jpmc26 Urban dictionary is hardly a credible reference.  As I said, you don't have to believe me, just don't be surprised if you offend someone.

Comment: @J... It's hardly one you should ignore, either. Look at Oxford's and MW's example sentences: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/native https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20native Cambridge says it can be used in a "humorous" way: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-native It's all based on context.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, and as is the way with humour, it takes a skilled hand to make that humour come out in the right way.  Especially for ELL/ESL speakers it is much too easy for this to come out in the wrong way - all I'm saying is that you have to be very careful about how you use this phrase.  It's an old expression and the minefields surrounding it are still live.

Answer (score 7):

Following up on a word mentioned by Andrew, you could consider *homogenizing*.

To *homogenize* something is to make it *homogeneous*: completely the same throughout, with no parts that are different from one another.  It can be done to milk, for instance; all the little bits of fat get mixed in, producing a uniform liquid from which the fat doesn't separate.

*Homogenize* sort of has the connotation that the resulting product is bland and boring, so I think it fits your negative usage a little better.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the phrase “losing your identity”.  While it appears to be going out of style, the US at least has considered assimilation and blending in a good thing.  It’s the great melting pot.  So, those terms are going to be considered positive by some people.

Losing your identity, forgetting where you came from or forgetting your roots, are all seen as uniformly negative.  Of these, I think the first is the most appropriate for your desired meaning.

Answer (score 1):

To *conform*

> Has there ever been a society which has died of dissent? Several have
>   died of conformity in our lifetime.
>
> -- Jacob Bronowski

.

> I think the reward for conformity is everyone likes you but yourself.
>
> -- Rita Mae Brown

Comment: Agreed, that came to my mind as well. It's rarely ever used with positive connotations. The sentence would have to be reworked around it, something like "Fitting in is one thing, but conformity is another" (the phrasing "a totally different thing" doesn't quite work with this word choice, as their literal definitions are very close).

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want to shift the focus here.

## Forgetting where you came from

The issue you want to emphasize is not the joining of the community, but the loss of the values and identity that someone learned in their original culture. In English, we're more explicit about this, since Western culture doesn't generally view adapting to the culture around you when you join it as a negative. Words like "assimilate" and "homogenize" won't quite convey the concept you want because they don't emphasize the loss to which you're trying to bring attention. Because they don't emphasize this point, they're going to sound awkward in your example context.

To "forget where you came from" is to abandon the values, beliefs, and distinctiveness of the culture you were raised in. It is a shift from participating in the culture you now live in to letting it determine your identity. It's a casual phrase (rather than formal), but it's also *very* negative. This seems to be what you're looking for. It can also imply that the listener may no longer care very much about the people they left behind, so be aware of that possible interpretation.

> Fitting in is one thing, but **forgetting where you came from** is a totally different thing.

Note that it's technically ungrammatical; it ends in a preposition. However, in casual discussion, this will not be a problem, if the listener even notices it.

Comment: **Thank you for your answer.** This is indeed a suitable suggestion to fill the blank with but not to convey what I actually want. This includes losses of things I'm not trying to achieve. I just want the loss of one's character, personality, interests, and the way s/he acts and behaves in a community s/he moved to temporarily, not the identity or culture.